# Resizing vmdk image (Virtualbox) and keep children

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running a virtualPC in virtualbox (Windows XP if it matters any) and I'd like to resize the image. I'm following [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190425140031/https://www.patricia-anong.com/blog/2017/11/1/extend-vmdk-on-virtualbox) (not super old, I just created an archive.org snapshot so the question lives on for when the blog eventually dies). All goes well until it comes to "releasing" the old disk. [With some further research](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=87136), I learned that I cannot release the disk because my disk happens to have children/snapshots. But I don't want to flatten the image if I don't have to, those snapshots are important. What can I do to increase the disk size while preserving the snapshots?

Answer (score 1):

You can not resize the disk with snapshot. In fact, if you could, your snapshot will be useless and unreadable. One option (not perfect) is maybe to copy the disk.